# Generating unique positive integers as id with ogr2ogr

Tags: python, gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, unique-id

I create an example GeoJSON:

```py
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd

s0 = shapely.wkt.loads("POINT(0 0)")
s1 = shapely.wkt.loads("POINT(1 1)")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[s0, s1],'data':['a','b']})

gdf.to_file("example.geojson")
```

Check it: `cat example.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

I would like each feature to have an `id`. I achieve that via [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) & the `ID_GENERATE` layer creation option (see [docs](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html)):

```py
ogr2ogr example_withIDs.geojson example.geojson -lco ID_GENERATE="YES"
```

Check the result via `cat example_withIDs.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "example",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

as expected. However, I would need all my `id`s to be positive.

**How can I generate unique positive integers as `id`s for each feature using `ogr2ogr`?**

---

Below I present attempts/clarifications, but no need to read them if one understands the question above.

---

**Attempt 1**

I tried to use the `ID_FIELD` layer creation option too:

```py
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT *, 12345 as generated_id FROM example" -dialect sqlite example_withIDs.geojson example.geojson -lco ID_FIELD='generated_id'
```

Check the result via `cat example_withIDs.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SELECT",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 12345, "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 12345, "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

All `id`s now are `12345`. If I could somehow enumerate rows starting from `1`, instead of having `12345 as generated_id` in the `SQL` statement, that would probably work.

---

**A note on `id`s**

Generating an `id` or `ID`, or similar field to be a member of `properties` is not what I am trying to achieve. A feature in a GeoJSON file looks like this:

```
   {
       "type": "Feature",
       "id": 12345, // <- I am talking about this id
       "geometry": {...},
       "properties": { "id": 12345, "ID": 12345 } // <- not about these
   }
```

I am talking about the `id` above which is on the same level as `type`, `geometry` and `properties`. Not about one of the `properties` elements. This is in line with section 3.2 of the [GeoJSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2):

> If a Feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier SHOULD be
> included as a member of the Feature object with the name "id", and the
> value of this member is either a JSON string or a number.

This is a separate thing from `properties`, which is:

> A Feature object has a member with the name "properties".  The value
> of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null
> value).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3047801/8565438) to the question [How to enumerate returned rows in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3047789/8565438), this seems to work:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS generated_id FROM example" \
        -dialect sqlite \
        example_withIDs.geojson example.geojson \
        -lco ID_FIELD='generated_id'
```

`example_withIDs.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SELECT",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: Question about a shortcoming of this method: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/449179/191643.

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve it with GeoPandas using the `index=None: bool` parameter

> If True, write index into one or more columns (for MultiIndex).
> Default None writes the index into one or more columns only if the
> index is named, is a MultiIndex, or has a non-integer data type. If
> False, no index is written.

```py
gdf.index += 1 
gdf.to_file("example.geojson", index=True)
```

It will result in:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "index": 1, "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "index": 2, "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

If you prefer having `"id"` instead of `"index"`, then execute the following code:

```py
gdf["id"] = gdf.index + 1
gdf.to_file("example.geojson")
```

then you end up with:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a", "id": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b", "id": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

And then you can simply rewrite your GeoJSON for example with this code:

```py
import json

with open("example.geojson", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

for record in data['features']:
    record['id'] = record['properties']['index'] #or record['properties']['id']
    del record['properties']['index'] #or record['properties']['id']

with open("example.geojson", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

to get this result:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"data": "a"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [0.0, 0.0]}, "id": 1},
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"data": "b"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [1.0, 1.0]}, "id": 2}
]
}
```

---

**References:**

- [start index at 1 for Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167930/start-index-at-1-for-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: In my real world application, it would be better not having to read in the whole GeoJSON using GeoPandas, and then again with `json.load`. If there is a way which yields the same result using no other tools than `ogr2ogr`, it would make my life easier. Nevertheless, this works, so thank you!

Comment: Sorry I am not good at `ogr2ogr`

Comment: I realize the question in the body asked `How can I generate unique positive integers as ids for each feature?` while only the post title asked for `ogr2ogr`: `How to generate unique positive integers as ids with ogr2ogr?`. I fixed this, now the question body also says: `How can I generate unique positive integers as ids for each feature using ogr2ogr?`. Sorry for not making this more clear earlier.

Comment: No worries. I think your post is useful for many future readers, even though it does not fully solve my problem in particular.