# Creating GeoJSON from GeoDataFrame with feature IDs but without bbox using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geojson, export, geopandas, geodataframe

Here is the creation of an example [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html), `gdf`:

```py
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd

s0 = shapely.wkt.loads("POINT(0 0)")
s1 = shapely.wkt.loads("POINT(1 1)")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[s0, s1],'data':['a','b']})
```

I would like to write its contents to a GeoJSON. I would like to have feature id for each feature, but not bounding box. Ideal output:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "id": "1", "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "id": "2", "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

My attempt:

```py
gdf.to_file("example.geojson")
```

`example.geojson` becomes:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

No `id` field. The thread [Adding a feature id when writing to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66366156/8565438) [provides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66387530/8565438) a way:

`gdf.__geo_interface__` is:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'id': '0',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'data': 'a'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (0.0, 0.0)},
   'bbox': (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)},
  {'id': '1',
   'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'data': 'b'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (1.0, 1.0)},
   'bbox': (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)}],
 'bbox': (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)}
```

I could write this into a text file, and I would have the `id`s I want (from `0`, not from `1`, but I can live with that). This method however also adds `bbox` fields, which I'd like to avoid.

How can I create a GeoJSON from a GeoDataFrame with Feature `id`s, but without `bbox`es using GeoPandas?

---

For those who just want to do it, no matter with what, [here is thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/447439/191643) doing the above with [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`to_json()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_json.html#geopandas-geodataframe-to-json) method:

```py
gdf.to_json()
```

It will result in this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":
        [
            {
                "id": "0",
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "data": "a"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [0.0, 0.0]
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "1",
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "data": "b"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [1.0, 1.0]
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the `layer_options` kwarg of [`to_file`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html):

```
gdf.to_file("example.geojson", engine="pyogrio", layer_options={"ID_GENERATE": "YES"})
```

Result:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "example",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

You can explicitly disable writing a `bbox`:

```
gdf.to_file(
    "example.geojson",
    engine="pyogrio",
    layer_options={"ID_GENERATE": "YES", "WRITE_BBOX": "NO"},
)
```

but that's the default setting, so it doesn't effect the output.