# How to keep property ids when recreating feature ids of a GeoJSON using ogr2ogr?

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have an example file, `example.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": "abc123", "properties": { "data": "a", "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": "abc123", "properties": { "data": "b", "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

It has both feature `id`s and `id` also appears in `properties`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": "abc123", "properties": { "data": "a", "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": "abc123", "properties": { "data": "b", "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]                      ^                                            ^
}                      |                                            |
                   feature id                                 id property
```

(More on feature `id`s: [GeoJSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946). Search for `"id"`.)

Following [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/447460/191643) to the question [Generating unique positive integers as id with ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/447439/191643), I do:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS generated_id FROM example" \
        -dialect sqlite \
        example_newids.geojson example.geojson \
        -lco ID_FIELD='generated_id'
```

`example_newids.geojson` becomes:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SELECT",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

The `id` field disappeared from `properties`. I would prefer this not to happen. Expected output:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SELECT",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "data": "a", "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "data": "b", "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

**What to modify on the `ogr2ogr` command above to avoid dropping `id`s from `properties`?**

If possible, I would prefer to not having to know anything about the input `GeoJSON` in advance, such as fields within `properties`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why, but this seems to work:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT geometry, id as id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS generated_id FROM id" -dialect sqlite id2.json id.json -lco ID_FIELD="generated_id"
```

Result:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SELECT",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "id": "abc123" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

The fields to select can be found with `ogrinfo file.json -al -so`. Most recent GDAL even supports ogrinfo output in JSON format that should help with parsing the result. See example below.

```
ogrinfo id.json -al -so -json
{
  "description":"id.json",
  "driverShortName":"GeoJSON",
  "driverLongName":"GeoJSON",
  "layers":[
    {
      "name":"id",
      "metadata":{
      },
      "geometryFields":[
        {
          "name":"",
          "type":"Point",
          "nullable":true,
          "extent":[
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1.0,
            1.0
          ],
          "coordinateSystem":{
            "wkt":"GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]",
            "projjson":{
              "$schema":"https://proj.org/schemas/v0.5/projjson.schema.json",
              "type":"GeographicCRS",
              "name":"WGS 84",
              "datum":{
                "type":"GeodeticReferenceFrame",
                "name":"World Geodetic System 1984",
                "ellipsoid":{
                  "name":"WGS 84",
                  "semi_major_axis":6378137,
                  "inverse_flattening":298.257223563
                }
              },
              "coordinate_system":{
                "subtype":"ellipsoidal",
                "axis":[
                  {
                    "name":"Geodetic latitude",
                    "abbreviation":"Lat",
                    "direction":"north",
                    "unit":"degree"
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"Geodetic longitude",
                    "abbreviation":"Lon",
                    "direction":"east",
                    "unit":"degree"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "id":{
                "authority":"EPSG",
                "code":4326
              }
            },
            "dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping":[
              2,
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "featureCount":2,
      "fields":[
        {
          "name":"data",
          "type":"String",
          "nullable":true,
          "uniqueConstraint":false
        },
        {
          "name":"id",
          "type":"String",
          "nullable":true,
          "uniqueConstraint":false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata":{
  },
  "domains":{
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, good point! It has the disadvantage of having to know the fields within `properties` in advance (if I don't want to lose those key-value pairs). Maybe I can get around that using `jq` or similar.

Comment: You can get a list of fields with ogrinfo.

Comment: Nice. I come up with a `jq` version (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449190/191643). My `ogrinfo` isn't updated enough so the `-json` flag does not work. Should probably update but a bit afraid I'm gonna break existing code. Once I update, I'll attempt to post a full solution using `ogrinfo` instead of `jq`, probably it's more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT \
        $(for key in $(cat example.geojson | jq --join-output '.features[0].properties | keys | join(" ")'); do echo -n "'example'.${key}, "; done)\
        'example'.geometry, \
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS generated_id \
        FROM 'example'" \
        -dialect sqlite \
        example_newids.geojson example.geojson \
        -lco ID_FIELD='generated_id'
```

It might be more elegant to follow the suggestion in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449183/191643) and use `ogrinfo` instead of `jq`.